# Dependency Walker for ubuntu

Tags: dependencies, executable, binary

Is there a tool like Windows [**DependencyWalker**](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) for Ubuntu ? I would like to see all shared libraries my executable depends on.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In a terminal, execute:

`ldd /path/to/your_executable`

Example:

```
~$ ldd /bin/ls
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff78fea000)
        libselinux.so.1 => /lib/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f1940858000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007f1940650000)
        libacl.so.1 => /lib/libacl.so.1 (0x00007f1940447000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f19400c4000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f193fec0000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1940a99000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f193fca2000)
        libattr.so.1 => /lib/libattr.so.1 (0x00007f193fa9d000)
```

Comment: There is one big difference beween ldd and depends - ldd does not show the hierarchy of dependencies. A shared library that I built links to 2 different versions of libicu, and I am unable to figure out which of the SOs that my library depends on is dependent on the "wrong" version. Is there some trick to have that hierarchical view?